# How to send agents to sink block if aging higher than threshold

Tags: anylogic

I am building a model where at any point in time if any agent is in system beyond threshold it has to go to Sink block. Is it possible to do it based on Agent time in system ?

If agents spent  180 days and beyond I want  to send it to write-off block
[image]

Comment: Please share some more details about the model setup. Are agents always in flow chart blocks? What sink? ... some tips: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Also, check the "emergency exit" example model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need to do first is to create an enter block that connects to your sink block
[image]

With that done, most of the blocks have a remove method associated, so you can do this, with any agent a:

```
a.currentBlock().remove(a);
enter.take(a);
```

Nevertheless, this is not good practice in my opinion, removing an agent from any block at any time will almost certainly mess up your flow logic in some way...

Comment: Is it possible to loop through entire Agent Population , identify agents who have spent x time in system and then move it to enter block ?

Comment: put an event inside the agent that triggers after x time... that would be more efficient

Comment: How do send the Agents in the Main Enter block within inside agent .  double x= (time()-dateToTime(due_date));
 if (x>180 && Value<5000) {
   enter.take();
 }

Comment: Agent (Agent#7[root.delay1]:null) can't be in several flowcharts at the time. At least two flowchart blocks are in conflict: root.enter and root.delay1  .. Getting this error . Below is the code I put at enter of delay block.                                                          double  days_due=(time())-dateToTime(agent.due_date);
traceln(days_due);
if (days_due<0 && agent.Value<50000){

delay1.remove(this);
enter.take(agent);
}

Comment: i have no idea what you are doing..... sorry, You will have to ask a brand new question

Comment: i have no way of knowing if "this" and "agent" are the same thing... they are problably not and they should be... so your code is wrong